# paying for food on Yom Tov

Tags: money, yom-tov

In my daf yomi study of Chapter 3 of Beitzah, people are going on the Yom Tov itself to butchers for meat and stores for groceries for their holiday meals.  There are all sorts of stipulations on how this is to be done, but I don't recall mention of payment for these food items.  I assume you can't pay with money on Yom Tov, so how did payment work?

Comment: See Shulchan Arukh 517 titled "How to buy food from a store on Yom Tov"

Comment: It’s actually discussed a little later on daf 29 (next week Wednesday daf)

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Beitzah.29b.8?lang=bi&p2=Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.323.4&lang2=bi&w2=Mishnah%20Berurah&lang3=en